# Trigger a button on page load

Tags: jquery, button, triggers, toggle, slide

I have this function

```
$("a#<?php echo $custom_jq_settings['toggle']; ?>").click(function() {
        jQuery("#<?php echo $custom_jq_settings['div']; ?>").slideToggle(400);
        jQuery("#featurepagination").toggle();
        jQuery("#featuretitlewrapper").toggle();
        return false;
    });
```

And this is the button I want to trigger on page load

```
<a href="#" id="featuretoggle" onclick="changeText('<?php if (is_front_page()) {?>Show<?php } else { ?>Show<?php } ?> Features');"><?php if (is_front_page()) {?>Hide<?php } else { ?>Hide<?php } ?> Features</a>
```

I would like to trigger that button when the page loads so that it starts open but then slides/closes

Comment: What is the question? What problem do you encounter?

Comment: Sorry the problem is that when the page loads up the button works to slide the div up and down but I want the div to load open like it does but then slide up example http://www.firstlutheranomaha.org/who-we-are

Comment: Also its the hide features, show features area im talking about, thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Does this not work?

```
<script>
    jQuery(function(){
      jQuery('#featuretoggle').click();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I added this into the header and it doesn't work http://www.firstlutheranomaha.org/who-we-are

Comment: You need to use jQuery instead of $. You should also put these scripts in the footer not the header. http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#js_bottom

Answer (score 6):

That's the easiest way:

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $("#featuretoggle").trigger("click");
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can trigger a [click event](http://api.jquery.com/click/) manually with jQuery:

```
$('#featuretoggle').click();
```

To do this when the page loads:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#featuretoggle').click();
});
```

I imagine you'll want this to be the last thing to happen when loading the page, so make sure it's the last line to be executed within `$(document).ready()`.

See this [example](http://jsfiddle.net/ArPJB/):

```
<a href="#" id="someButton">Foo</a>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        // bind the click event
        $('#someButton').click(function() {
            alert('baz');
        });

        // trigger the click event
        $('#someButton').click();
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want is can be achived by using setTimeout() function.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        $("a#<?php echo $custom_jq_settings['toggle']; ?>").trigger('click');
    },10);
});
```

This will work for you surely...