# Button not being triggered when page is loaded? (JQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cordova, jquery-mobile

I am attempting to get a button (#directions-button) to be triggered when the page is loaded as I already have data from a previous page being parsed into the textfield (#target-dest) for when the page is loaded, however I cannot get the button to be triggered automatically as soon as the page loads.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var locn = location.href;
    var locationPortions = locn.split("?loc=");
    $("#target-dest").val(locationPortions[1]);
    $("#directions-button").trigger('click');
});
```

```html
<a href="#" id="directions-button" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-mini="true">
    Get Directions
</a>
```

Comment: Have you checked the console for errors? Are there multiple `#directions-button` elements in the page?

Comment: It's a mobile app and I am testing on my phone so I don't really have a debugger. But yes, target-dest textfield is being populated correctly so the elements from the page are definitely working.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8840044/trigger-a-button-on-page-load duplicate

Comment: Here is the code in jsfiddle, if anyone can see any issues? https://jsfiddle.net/ubecwq1k/#&togetherjs=DTiFxL8wr8

Comment: instead of $( document ).ready(function() {... use the jqm pageshow event.

Comment: @ezanker Button is still not being triggered. So confused to what it could be..

Comment: From comments below looks like your button gets clicked, but your code doesn't show any action to be taken when that click occurs

Comment: Here is your updated fiddle with the triggered click working: https://jsfiddle.net/ubecwq1k/6/

Comment: @ezanker The map is still not being displayed...I'm thinking maybe the data is not parsed into the textfield in time for the button to read it and display the route and directions? Hence why the alert is appearing but the route is not being displayed...?

Answer (score -1):

I don't see an even handler for when the button is clicked. Also you should define the handler before triggering the click event.

Have a look at

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var locn = location.href;
  var locationPortions = locn.split("?loc=");
  $("#target-dest").val(locationPortions[1]);

  $("#directions-button").click(function() {
    alert('I was clicked');
  })

  $("#directions-button").trigger('click');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a href="#" id="directions-button" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-mini="true">
    Get Directions
</a>
```

this https://jsfiddle.net/v7h0dbga/

Comment: The alert worked as it appeared on the interface, but the button still was not triggered? Slightly Strange.

Comment: What do you mean "the button still was not triggered"? If the alert worked then the button was triggered. What do you expect to happen that is not happening? What does "triggered" mean to you?

Comment: The snippet above shows that the click event is triggered on page load. Not sure what you're really looking for.

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
$( "#directions-button" ).click();
```

Answer (score -1):

Your code as written works fine. See this updated Fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/ubecwq1k/2/ which pops up an alert to prove it. I had to include JQuery as a resource and use jsfiddle properly (JS in JS pane, HTML in HTML pane, etc.). Click run and you'll see the handler I've added:

```
...
$("#directions-button").click(function () { alert('works'); });
$("#directions-button").trigger("click");
```

is in fact fired.

Comment: The alert is working, however the button still is not being triggered. Do you think this may be to do with something in the javascript file for the map?

Comment: As I mentioned on Angad's answer: what do you mean "the button still was not triggered"? If the alert worked then the button was triggered. What do you expect to happen that is not happening? What does "triggered" mean to you?

Comment: I have updated jsfiddle with the javascript file for the actual maps

Comment: The data I am getting from a previous page is a location of an event, for example "tower bridge, london". this then gets parsed and is populated in the textfield "#target-dest" so the page is then ready for the route to be displayed. This is done when you click the "#directions-button", a route is shown on the map as well as directions below, however this is not occuring. So, I am still having to press it manually.

Comment: I don't get anything happening in your fiddle when I press it manually. Do you actually get the content to show in the fiddle or locally? Is there code missing?

Comment: No, nothing will appear of course as it's google maps and has other external sources that are local. But I put the javascript code behind google maps. I thought maybe there is something in there that may cause the button to be triggered on page load.

Comment: I see a reference to maptest.js, is that code not present in the fiddle?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108420/discussion-between-mahdi-and-steve-at-idv).

Comment: I'm thinking maybe the data is not parsed into the textfield in time for the button to read it and display the route and directions? Hence why the alert is appearing but the route is not being displayed...?

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
$("#directions-button").on('click',function() {
    alert('clicked');
})

$("#directions-button").trigger("click");
```

Comment: As per my other comments, the alerts are working yet the button is still not being triggered. I was thinking that the problem could be to do with the javascript file for the google maps?

Comment: Is there any JavaScript error? Check the console, maybe there is some error that is stopping your code for running.

Comment: I'm checking your jsfiddle and I don't see action implemented for the clicking event. Where is the implementation of the click event for the anchor tag?

Comment: it's a mobile app and I am testing on my phone so I don't really have a debugger. Not sure what you mean in the latter part

Comment: As mentioned in other comments, i am getting the alerts but the button is not performing the action of displaying the route and directions, only does it work when i manually press it.

Comment: In order to see what's happening I need to be able to check the code you have in the handle of the click event. I think there is a missing part here. For what I see you don't have the handle in your jsfiddle.

Comment: I'm thinking maybe the data is not parsed into the textfield in time for the button to read it and display the route and directions? Hence why the alert is appearing but the route is not being displayed...?