# How to turn a Bootstrap Modal into a popup on page load?

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4

I need to put a popup onto a website to tell users that there is a new version of the site.

I've created a Bootstrap modal that works on click, but using jQuery, is it possible to make it appear after a few seconds once the page has loaded? 
And once closed to not appear again?

Please see my code below, and  [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ye8w2tc6/6/)

```
<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModalCenter">
    Launch demo modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModalCenter" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle"><img src="https://dcnetworks.ie/wp/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/placeholder-logo-2-300x167.png" style="width: 300px;"/></h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true" style="font-size: 35px;">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <h2>Lorem lorem lorem <br />
                   Ipum ipsum</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer popup-buttons-wrap">
                <button type="button" class="btn visit-button"><h3>Visit Site</h3></button>
                <button type="button" class="btn close-button" data-dismiss="modal"><h3>Close</h3></button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

```
.modal-title{
    text-align: center;
}
.modal-content{
    background-color: #063242;
    height: 500px;
    width: 750px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
}
.modal-body{
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
.modal-body h2{
    width: 60%;
    border-left: 3px solid #E52149;
    border-right: 3px solid #ADD13D;
    font-weight: 400;
}
.modal-header{
    border-bottom: 0;
}
.modal-footer{
    border-top: 0;
    text-align: center;
}
.modal-header .close{
    color: #fff;
    position: absolute;
    top: 25px;
    right: 25px;
}
.visit-button{
    border: 3px solid #E52149;
    background-color: transparent;
    margin-right: 55px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0;
    -moz-border-radius: 0;
    border-radius: 0;
}
.visit-button h3{
    margin: 0;
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: 400;
    padding: 3px;
}
.visit-button:hover{
    background-color: #E52149;
    color: #fff;
}
.close-button{
    border: 3px solid #ADD13D;
    background-color: transparent;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0;
    -moz-border-radius: 0;
    border-radius: 0;
}
.close-button h3{
    margin: 0;
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: 400;
    padding: 3px;
}
.close-button:hover{
    background-color: #ADD13D;
    color: #fff;
}
```

Comment: is your question "without using jquery"...? also, as it is now, your modal is loaded when I open the fiddle.

Comment: No, I'm trying to use jQuery to make it work.  I'm not sure why it's open on jsfiddle, on my site it remains closed until I click on the button

Comment: it sounds like you want to fire some code when the page is loaded... so you'll want to check out the jquery "ready" function, there is some information on running that here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8840044/trigger-a-button-on-page-load

Comment: Thanks for the link, that sounds like what I want.  I've tried $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#exampleModalCenter').click();
}); but doesn't seem to be working

Answer (score 0):

Try to do this:

```
if (typeof $.cookie('yourCookie') === 'undefined')
  //Create yourCookie and display your modal
else
  //Go on your website
```